# How can i sent ETH from a contract wallet to another account?

Tags: transactions, accounts, wallets, mist, contract-invocation

Use the mist wallet 0.3.9.

The ETH from a pool is sent to a wallet address. How can I send the ETH from wallet to account?

When I try to send from the wallet address to an exchange address, I saw only *execute contract* from account address to a wallet address. What does that mean? How can i sent ETH from a contract wallet to another account?

Comment: Just to be clear about a few things so I understood you correctly.

1. You created a wallet contract via Mist
2. You received Ether to this wallet contract
3. You now want to sent from this wallet contract to a normal account

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy.

1. Open the wallet and press "Send";
2. Select your wallet contract at the "From" select;
3. In the "To" field paste the address of the contract or account you want to send the Ether to.
4. Fill in an amount to send;

Ethereum doesn't discriminate between contracts and accounts, on the protocol level these are all the same so the instructions on how to send are the same as well :)

Comment: Every of these steps completed, but when i click on a send button, opens a window with Execute Contract from account address to wallet address, and i can't change it. At account address no eth (just 0.09). Maybe this transaction don't free? And wallet try get cost ?

Comment: Set bigger cost for transaction = transaction completed. Answer was found by myself

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is exactly what is to be expected. Contract Wallets have Accounts as owners. A Contract Wallet can have a single owner Account, or if it is a multisig Contract Wallet it will have more than one owner Account.

The owner Account/s for the Contract Wallet you are sending from must give its approval. A transaction must be sent from the owner Account to the Contract Wallet. The owner Account will only need to have enough ether to cover the gas cost of this transaction.

Just enter the password of the Account as requested and the ether transfer from Contract Wallet to Account will go through. I am assuming you are using a single-owner Contract Wallet (Simple Wallet).